# Unable to highlight the background of the dynamically created TableLayout rows on click of the rows Android

Tags: android

I have dynamically created a TableLayout programmatically. But I am unable to highlight any row whenever it is clicked.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and customize for click on table row:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);

        LinearLayout ActiveItem = (LinearLayout) view;
        ActiveItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);    
    }
```

background_dark_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
            <!-- border width and color -->

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FF0404B4" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />
        </shape></item>

</layer-list>
```

**edit**

for automatic selection you should have a xml in color folder like back_color_selector_blue_gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_dark_blue" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

state_orange.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
</shape>
```

in the layout adapter of your list or table set the following property for LinearLayout:

```
android:background="@color/back_color_selector_blue_gradient"
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the help, the above thing works well, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. I want to highlight(change background color of the row similar to button click ) the row only till the time the user presses it, once released it should retain its old color.

Comment: Hello,
I tried your edited solution, but I am getting the following exception:

11-27 15:46:43.754: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(499): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/color_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001

11-27 15:46:43.754: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(499): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable


Although I have properly placed the resource file at the specified location

Comment: you should define state_orange.xml and background_dark_blue.xml in 'res\drawable' folder

Comment: They are there in the res\drawable folder

Comment: refreshed and restarted eclipse too. still the problem :(

Comment: did you define the @color/orange in the res\values\color.xml?

Comment: yes I set it to my own color

I've been trying to solve this issue since yesterday,spent hours but unable to make it work :(

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/back_color_selector_blue_gradient">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="50px" android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:text="Hello"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="150px" android:text="Kaps" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: I am inflating the above xml to create a Tablerow for my dynamic table Please have a look if I am missing smething :

Comment: background_dark_blue.xml and state_orange.xml are there inside res\drawable folder

Also apart from xml changes I don't have to change anything in my code right?

Comment: Hello,
It is picking up the background color now,but the color is not changing onclick

Comment: Thank You so much . It worked. I was missing the following attributes :
android:focusable="true" 
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:clickable="true"